# ASP MVC Identity - change default database in a database first approach

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, forms-authentication, owin

I am used to working with database first.  Created a ASP MVC5 project with logins enabled and the default settings creates a database under default connection with all relevant tables (like AspNetUser etc). What I would like to achieve is have these tables in my own database (maybe even named differently Users, Roles etc). Not even sure where I would need to begin. 
Configure auth uses this

```
            app.CreatePerOwinContext(ApplicationDbContext.Create);
```

which in turn uses DefaultConnection as shown below

```
    public ApplicationDbContext()
        : base("DefaultConnection", throwIfV1Schema: false)
    {
    }
```

- I changed the default connection to the connection that points to my database.
- I changed my database context to implement IdentityDBContext. Now, when I try to login I get an error message that says IdentityUserLogin is not part of the model context.

I am assuming I would need to manually create the relevant tables. Is that correct? How will I be able to change the table names? Any steps in the right direction of how to integrate auth within another database would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you implement IdentityDbContext interface?

Comment: Yes. Should I create the tables in my database with the exact same names such as Aspnetusers etc? my class if now public partial class MyEntities : IdentityDbContext

Comment: No, if you implemented IdentityDbContext , then when you will create database in MS SQL - code automatically will create this database. If you already have database - just try do migration and update database

Comment: It breaks at this line - var result = await SignInManager.ExternalSignInAsync(loginInfo, isPersistent: false);

Comment: Just curious - if I wanted to  go about this in a database first approach with my own table names say "users" "roles" and so on there is no way to wire it back with the generated code? Just jittery since the database is maintained by a different team and we follow DB first for separation of concerns

Answer (score 1):

If you want replace default tables:

```
 protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

            // Renaming default ASP.NET tables
            modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUser>().ToTable("Users");
            modelBuilder.Entity<User>().ToTable("Users");
            modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserRole>().ToTable("UserRoles");
            modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserLogin>().ToTable("UserLogins");
            modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserClaim>().ToTable("UserClaims");
            modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityRole>().ToTable("Roles");



        }
```

Comment: this goes in my dbcontext? so if I create the user tables etc in the db generate the edmx and add these lines it should work?

Comment: Im not sure about edmx...just try it , but this is way how work with your own tables

Comment: thank you for answering but im still confused. Can you also point me to the code where entity framework initially creates the tables in the original MDF file?